# UIImage initWithContentsOfFile doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimage, imagenamed, initwithcontentsoffile

I have question: I want to avoid [UIImage imageNamed:].
So i did:

```
UIImage *prodImg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"myimage.png"]; 
controller.productImg.image = prodImg;  
[prodImg release];
```

But now the image is not shown anymore.

Does anyone know how to get that to work?

Comment: Ok, I got it working with UIImage *prodImg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"my image" ofType:@"png"]];

Comment: suggestion: just use `[UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage.png"]` because it adds caching and device extension ("@2x", "~ipad") logic

Comment: With [UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage.png"] I get memory warnings, see here http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/2009/01/13/imagenamed-is-evil/

Comment: that might be because you hang on to the UIImages for a long time.. if you just assign it to a UIImageView and don't retain it you sould be fine. AND using jpg-Files on iOS is dangerous for memory consumption (use png-format and `pngcrush -iphone` command-line tool).

Comment: +1 for imageNamed is evil. Saw exactly the same effect. Proposed solution eliminated out of memory warning and eliminated crashes.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The above code is not working because correct way to do it is-

```
NSString *thePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"default" ofType:@"jpeg"];
UIImage *prodImg = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:thePath]; 
controller.productImg.image = prodImg;  
[prodImg release];
```

;)