# Loading images for animation in UIImageView - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, nsarray

I have around 300 images to be loaded for animation the images are named `loading001.png, loading002.png, loading003.png, loading004.png………loading300.png`

I am doing it in the following way.

**.h file**

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    @interface CenterViewController : UIViewController  {
        UIImageView *imgView;
    }

    @end
```

**.m file**

```
@implementation CenterViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    imgView.animationImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"loading001.png"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"loading002.png"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"loading003.png"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"loading004.png"],
                               nil];
}

- (IBAction)startAnimation:(id)sender{
    [imgView startAnimating];
}

@end
```

Is there a efficient way to load the images into a array.
I had tried it with `for loop` but was not able to figure it out.

Comment: here is a sample code http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-animation-uiimageview/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You may try out the following code to load images into an array in a better way

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableArray *imgListArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i=1; i <= 300; i++) {
        NSString *strImgeName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"loading%03d.png", i];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:strImgeName];
            if (!image) {
                NSLog(@"Could not load image named: %@", strImgeName);
            }
            else {
                [imgListArray addObject:image];
            }
        }
    imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    [imgView setAnimationImages:imgListArray];
}
```

Comment: You have an empty space in the strImageName @"loading %4d.png should be @loading%4d.png"

Comment: Should be [NSString stringWithFormat:@"loading%03d.png", i];

Comment: Thanks all it worked. I had tried something similar but was stuck at `loading%03.png`.

Comment: Use of UIImageView.animationImages will crash your device before long. Lots of lot of people run into this problem, the real solution is to not use UIImageView to do your animations.

Comment: @MoDJ I had used the above piece of code for max 20 image animation, I agree with you the app may crash, and thanks for the link. +1 for digging up old question

Answer (score 3):

There is an easier way to do this. You can simply use:

```
[UIImage animatedImageNamed:@"loading" duration:1.0f]
```

Where `1.0f` is the duration to animate all the images. For this to work though, your images must be named like this:

```
loading1.png
loading2.png
.
.
loading99.png
.
.
loading300.png
```

That is, without padding with 0.

The function `animatedImageNamed` is available from iOS 5.0 onwards.

Comment: how to stop this animation? You have an idea?

Comment: @yucelbayram Must set on animatedImages for repeat count to take effect. Can set last image for when complete. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29621400/uiimageview-animationrepeatcount-strange-behaviour#answer-29623852

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the size of your images, a 300 image animation sequence may be quite the memory hog.  Using a a movie might be a better solution.

Comment: My images are small so going forward with image animation.

Answer (score 2):

Your code will crash when run on the device, it is just not possible to decompress that many images into memory on iOS. You will get memory warnings and then your app will be killed by the OS. See my answer to [how-to-do-animations-using-images-efficiently-in-ios](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17129053/763355) for a solution that will not crash on the device.