# Images animation in UIImageview not smooth

Tags: ios, uiimageview, caanimation

I have 61 images for animate the imageview. Iphone4 it crash due to memory problem.. Some time animation slow and the animation progress not linear.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 61; i++)
        [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", i]]];

lImageView.animationImages = images;
lImageView.animationDuration = 4.0f;
[lImageView startAnimating];
```

This is my code.. How to show like gif images in linear manner. I search lot most of them post this only.

for (int i = 1; i <= 61; i++)
        [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", i]]];

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];
animation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationDiscrete;
animation.duration = images.count / 24.0f;
animation.values = images;
animation.repeatCount = 1;
animation.delegate = self;
[lImageView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animation"];
```

Below code crash due to nil in array. That is imageWithContentsOfFile: this i didnt got the image.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 61; i++)
            [images addObject: [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:imagename ofType:@".png"]]];

    lImageView.animationImages = images;
    lImageView.animationDuration = 4.0f;
    [lImageView startAnimating];
```

I tried this also this not start animation.. I didn't see any animation in above.. Any help Highly appreciable.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am not sure but use [UIImage imagewithcontentofFile:] in place of [UIImage imagenamed:] , bcz imagenamed: eat to much memory and let me know, its helpful or not.

Comment: @Er.ShreyanshShah : Hi imagewithcontentofFile: use this means returns nil, What is my issue?

Comment: Can paste ur code in comment or in question. ? So i can identify.

Comment: No dear.. U have to take it From bundle. As [NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:imagename ofType:@".png">

Comment: Thanks for your response dear.. but still I didnt get linear animation..

Comment: This question has been asked and answered many many times on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617910/loading-images-for-animation-in-uiimageview-ios/17225223#17225223