# UIImageView animationRepeatCount strange behaviour

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

So i have this code that animates a set of images an unlimited amount of times just fine, however as soon as i try to limit the number of times it animates it simply does not work. No image is even displayed.

Code that works:

```
animatedMap.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"0.gif"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.gif"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.gif"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.gif"],
                               //etc...];
animatedMap.animationDuration = 20.0f;
animatedMap.animationRepeatCount = 0;
[animatedMap startAnimating];
```

Code that doesn't work:

```
animatedMap.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"0.gif"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.gif"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.gif"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.gif"],
                               //etc...];
animatedMap.animationDuration = 20.0f;
animatedMap.animationRepeatCount = 1;
[animatedMap startAnimating];
```

This just seems like really strange behaviour?

Comment: Could you find answer of your question? I stuck in same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I noticed the same behavior, my solution was to put the start of animation code in a different place.

For me, it was a View Controller, so I put `imageView.startAnimating()` in `viewWillAppear:` instead of `viewDidLoad:`.

I don't 100% understand what is the problem, but one can assume that the animation doesn't fire because by setting the `animationRepeatCount` to 1, your "one animation" happens before the view is displayed. To be more technical, the `CATransaction::Commit` with the one animation gets performed *before* the view is displayed, and not when the view *is* displayed.

Comment: YES!!  Thank you, this was my problem too.  Setting everything up and calling startAnimating() in viewDidLoad() worked fine, until I tried to set animationRepeatCount to non-zero, then the image just disappeared.  Moving the setup to viewWillAppear made it work perfectly!

Comment: I have the same issue but it is happening when I try to animate from a speech synthesizer delegate did finish method. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60766734/animation-not-playing-inside-speech-synthesizer-delegate?noredirect=1#comment107525325_60766734

Answer (score 2):

`animationRepeatCount` is used for cycle all the images in given `animationDuration` duration.

So if you provide `animatedMap.animationRepeatCount = 1;` that means only 1 cycle will be run and then the default set image will be displayed. If you didn't define default image to `UIImageView` then it will be blank(i.e. background color of `UIImageView` )

There is possibility to have more images then the given time duration for animation, which leads to super-fast animation.

**Update 1**

You can set last image just before starting your animation.

```
NSArray *imgArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"0.gif"],
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.gif"],
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.gif"],
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.gif"],
                           //etc...];
[animatedMap setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imgArray lastObject]]];
animatedMap.animationImages = imgArray
animatedMap.animationDuration = 20.0f;
animatedMap.animationRepeatCount = 0;
[animatedMap startAnimating];
```

Comment: So how would i go about getting it to only do the whole cycle once?

Comment: `animatedMap.animationRepeatCount = [animatedMap.animationImages count];` maybe?

Comment: If you want to make your cycle only for single time, then you can set default image just before starting the animation.