# swift: repeat animation after time

Tags: ios, swift

I have this animation:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
_ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 15, target: self, selector: #selector(self.callingFunction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc func callingFunction(){
        let image0:UIImage = UIImage(named: "next0.png")!
        let image1:UIImage = UIImage(named: "next1.png")!
        let image2:UIImage = UIImage(named: "next2.png")!
        let image3:UIImage = UIImage(named: "next3.png")!
        let image4:UIImage = UIImage(named: "next4.png")!
        let image5:UIImage = UIImage(named: "next5.png")!
        let image6:UIImage = UIImage(named: "next6.png")!
        let image7:UIImage = UIImage(named: "next7.png")!

        nextButton.setImage(image0, for: .normal)
        nextButton.imageView!.animationImages = [image0, image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6, image7]
        nextButton.imageView!.animationDuration = 1.0
        nextButton.imageView!.startAnimating()
    }
```

I need to repeat this animation in every 15 seconds. But this animation starts after 15 seconds and next execute every 1 second.

Comment: Timers. You can start with them.

Comment: Can you elaborate more?

Comment: @PiyushRathi I want to repeat animation in every 15 seconds.

Comment: have you checked with it imageView.animationRepeatCount

Comment: @PiyushRathi In this case my animation execute every 1 second. And stops after 15 seconds.

Comment: Can you show your start animating method?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri updated

Comment: @IraniyaNaynesh nextButton.imageView!.startAnimating()

Comment: try imageView.animationRepeatCount

Comment: @IraniyaNaynesh Please read the comments. Tried it.

Comment: You mean to say when you call timer it starts after 15 sec, but images shuffle in 1.0 sec?

Comment: you should read the repeat count behaviors if you are using from viewDidLodad https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29621400/uiimageview-animationrepeatcount-strange-behaviour

Comment: @PiyushRathi Yes!

Comment: So you need to increase/decrease value of 'animationDuration'

Comment: @PiyushRathi I need that every 15 seconds my animation with duration 1 second execute. For example. 15 seconds not animation -> animation start with duration 1 second -> 15 seconds not animation -> animation start with duration 1 second -> 15 seconds not animation -> animation start with duration 1 second ...

Comment: @PiyushRathi I need an animation with a duration of 1 second to be executed every 15 seconds.

Comment: Got you, just you need to set animationRepeatCount = 1 (this will help image change will stop in one), and when timer reach to 15sec then again call your callingFunction..

Comment: have you got my Point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just Updating your code**

Just you need to set animationRepeatCount = 1 (this will help image change will stop in one), and when a timer reaches to 15sec then again call your callingFunction.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    /// You need to take class object here for timer, when viewWillDisapper called you need to invalidate timer other wise you will fase memory issues
    self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 15, target: self, selector: #selector(self.timerTimeUp), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc func timerTimeUp() {
    self.callingFunction()
}

func callingFunction(){
    let image0:UIImage = UIImage(named: "next0.png")!
    let image1:UIImage = UIImage(named: "next1.png")!
    let image2:UIImage = UIImage(named: "next2.png")!
    let image3:UIImage = UIImage(named: "next3.png")!
    let image4:UIImage = UIImage(named: "next4.png")!
    let image5:UIImage = UIImage(named: "next5.png")!
    let image6:UIImage = UIImage(named: "next6.png")!
    let image7:UIImage = UIImage(named: "next7.png")!

    nextButton.setImage(image0, for: .normal)
    nextButton.imageView!.animationImages = [image0, image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6, image7]
    nextButton.imageView!.animationDuration = 1.0
    nextButton.imageView!.animationRepeatCount = 1
    nextButton.imageView!.startAnimating()
}
```

**Updated Code**

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.invalidateTimer()
}

func invalidateTimer() {
   if self.timer != nil {
      self.timer.invalidate()
      self.timer = nil
   }
}
```

You can call `invalidateTimer()` method, whenever view dismiss/Disappear.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: in `viewWillDisapper ` I should call `timer.invalidate()`?

Comment: @piyushRathi why timerTimeUp() function here. Even you didn't call

Comment: @PranavanSp I just copied paste code, I forgot to change it. Now updated.

Comment: @user yes but you need to take an object as 'timer'

Comment: @PiyushRathi Thank you! But could I add code for remove timer in `viewWillDisapper ` in answer. Please?

Answer (score 1):

You have to call function by using timer. Set timeInterval to 15 seconds.

```
callingFunction()
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 15, target: self, selector: #selector(self.callingFunction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func callingFunction(){
      //Execute your code
      let image0:UIImage = UIImage(named: "next0.png")!
let image1:UIImage = UIImage(named: "next1.png")!
let image2:UIImage = UIImage(named: "next2.png")!
let image3:UIImage = UIImage(named: "next3.png")!
let image4:UIImage = UIImage(named: "next4.png")!
let image5:UIImage = UIImage(named: "next5.png")!
let image6:UIImage = UIImage(named: "next6.png")!
let image7:UIImage = UIImage(named: "next7.png")!

nextButton.setImage(image0, for: .normal)
nextButton.imageView!.animationImages = [image0, image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6, image7]
nextButton.imageView!.animationDuration = 1.0
nextButton.imageView!.animationRepeatCount = 1
nextButton.imageView!.startAnimating()
}
```

Comment: Sorry. I need repeat animation in every 15 second

Comment: @user yes. you can achieve by this

Comment: In your code after 15 second create loop and repeat animation after 0 second.

Comment: @user can you clearly state here what you expected to do. i could not get you

Comment: I want to repeat animation in every 15 seconds. In you code animation repeat after 15 seconds one time and next repeat after 0 second (loop).

Comment: @user you can do it by calling it then set timer. Check my edited answer

Comment: Same result. First time animation call after 15 seconds. Second time animation call immediately. And next animations calls immediately.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177695/discussion-between-pranavan-sp-and-user).

Comment: @user try to add nextButton.imageView!.animationRepeatCount = 1. edited answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use a timer:

```
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 15, repeats: true) {
     [weak self] (timer) in
     self?.nextButton.imageView?.startAnimating()
}
```

To stop it:

```
timer.invalidate()
```

Comment: Sorry I need repeat animation in every 15 second

Comment: see the `repeats: true` param @user

Comment: your code after 15 second create loop animation with delay 0.

Comment: I want to repeat animation in every 15 seconds. In you code animation repeat after 15 seconds one time and next repeat after 0 second (loop).